# function firing multiple times when scrolling fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scroll, infinite-scroll

First of all, I'm not very advanced at code and tend to only do this part time so please excuse all terrible/ugly code! I appreciate there are already some solutions out there but I can't seem to make any of them work with my code so would really appreciate some help!

I'm using isotope grid and trying to setup an infinite scroll. I want to load 10 images at a time when the user scrolls to the bottom by taking these images from an array and appending them to a temp div.

This is working perfectly when scrolling slowly, but as soon as you scroll quickly the function seems to fire multiple times, it gets a little glitchy and loads lots of images at once.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var docuHeight = $(document).height();

if(scrollTop + windowHeight == docuHeight){

  nextTenImages = imagesData.splice(0,10);
  var content = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < nextTenImages.length; i++) {
      content +=
      "<div class='box " + nextTenImages[i]["type"] + "'" + ">" +
        "<div class='box-wrapper'>" +
          "<img src='" + nextTenImages[i]["src"] + "' />" +
        "</div>" +
      "</div>"
  };

  $('body').append('<div id="temp-load"><div id="grid"></div></div>');
  $('#temp-load > #grid').append(content)

  $('#temp-load > #grid').children().css({
      opacity: 0
  });

  var toAdd = $('#temp-load > #grid').html();

  $container.isotope('insert', $(toAdd), function(){
    $container.children().css({
      opacity: 1
    });
    $('#temp-load').remove();
  });

}

});
```

Comment: The concept is like asking for extra water to five waiter. Each will bring thinking they were the only one. What is required if you tell 1 waiter, then refrain from telling more till that waiter gets back to you. On a similar note, once your image loader function is triggered, wait for the image to be loaded and the document length to be updated before accepting new trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Make a single timeout to run the callback. This may avoid the function from executing multiple times.

```
var timer;

function scrollEvt() {
    /* scroll actions */
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    /* clear the old timeout */
    clearTimeout(timer);
    /* wait until 400 ms for callback */
    timer = setTimeout(scrollEvt, 400);
});
```

Using other ways may result in problems (like comparing `(window.performance || Date).now()`)...

Comment: No, you have to debounce it, meaning you need to clear any prvious timeout, e.g using: `clearTimeout(timer);` before setting a new one

Comment: You are right just that sunday is my lazy day... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unbind that specific scroll event till your delayed operation is completed to prevent accumulating more of the event triggers which create the duplication behaviour as in your case.

```js
var winCached = $(window),
  docCached = $(document)

var currLeng = 0;

function addContent() {
  dettachScrollEvent();
  setTimeout(function() { //this timeout simulates the delay from the ajax post
    for (var i = currLeng; i < currLeng + 100; i++)
      $('div').append(i + '<br />');
    currLeng = i;
    console.log("called loader!");
    attachScrollEvent();
  }, 500);

}

function infiNLoader() {
  if (winCached.scrollTop() + winCached.height() > docCached.height() - 300) {
    addContent();
    //alert("near bottom! Adding more dummy content for infinite scrolling");
  }
}

function attachScrollEvent() {

  winCached.scroll(infiNLoader);
}

function dettachScrollEvent() {
  winCached.unbind('scroll', infiNLoader);
}
addContent();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```